# Angular: Boolean @Input vs Attribute @Directive - which to use?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-components

What I want to do using Angular is to create a "directive" that adds a something to my component, lets say a `myPortlet` with `myHasCloseButton` gives `myPortlet` a close button.

```
<myPortlet myHasCloseButton>...</myPortlet>
```

I found three options how to approach this and I'm not sure which one is the correct one or if I missed a better option.

**Option 1:**
Create a directive that does something like

```
this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.myCloseButton').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

- Presence of directive enables the button which is syntactically awesome (see above).
- Can be applied to more than myPortlets which allows a more flexible use.
- Does not allow for `*ngIf`, thus forcing each `myPortlet` and other components to carry a hidden `myCloseButton` which feels awkward and appears to be not recommended.
- Does not allow to bind to some boolean property.

**Option 1a:**
Just like Option 1, but give the directive an boolean `@Input` that switches the application of the visibility.

- Allows to bind some boolean property.
- Presence of directive no longer sufficient, usage is now

  ...

**Option 2:**
Give myPortlet a boolean `@Input` and a `*ngIf` directive at the right place.

- No close-button generated where unnecessary.
- Allows for binding a boolean.
- Must be implemented seperatly for each component using it.
- Presence of directive no longer sufficient, see above.

**Option 2b:**
"Hackily" give a string `@Input` instead and check if it's empty (as that's what happens when you just give the input name without anything after) and treat it as true.

- Presence of directive enables the button which is syntactically awesome (see above).
- Does not allow to bind to some boolean property except maybe by typecasting boolean to string.

**Option 3:**
Create a directive that actually injects the myCloseButton via something like

```
ElementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.myCloseButton').addComponent(myCloseButton)
```

[No actual tested Syntax, just an example, not sure if addComponent is the correct function and how to use it]

- Somehow feels awkward, seems like bad practice and overcomplicated.
- Using `Elementref` is warned against in Angular Docs, appears dangerous.
- Forces each `myPortlet` and other components to carry a hidden `myCloseButton` container.
- `myPortlet` (or other component) no longer has control over the embedded `myCloseButton`.
- Due to that, it might be more difficult to achieve communication between `myPortlet` and the embedded `myCloseButton` (especially of `myCloseButton` is something more complex).

So my question is: Which is the recommended approach? Am I missing any option? Any best practices? None of those options feels right.

Comment: I seriously have no idea why the format brakes at Option1a code sample and after. If some mod got an idea...

Comment: @fortuneNxt about the formatting, the line breaks before the lists make a difference. I fixed it for you. Have a look at the diff (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48428341/revisions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@Input()` is best for this use case.

It's simple, clean, and most importantly, it allows you to *dynamically* determine whether your component has a close button (a nice feature you could not get with the attribute directive). Example (this is terrible UX), but what if you only wanted to allow admin users to have a close button. Then, you could subscribe to your user service and set `[hasCloseButton]="userIsAdmin$ | async"`. That's pretty powerful stuff you couldn't do (in a clean way) with an attribute directive.

Also, for testing, you can just set the input directly (`testComponent.hasCloseButton = true`), rather than having to create a test host component and create one case with the directive / one without.

To summarize: using `@Input()` will afford you more flexibility and make testing easier.